# Read JSON and assign to a list of make variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can get a value from `package.json` with this:

```
LAST_VERSION := $(shell node -p "require('./package.json').version")
```

But what if I need several values? Like:

```
PROJECT     := $(shell node -p "require('./package.json').name")
LAST_VERSION:= $(shell node -p "require('./package.json').version")
DESCRIPTION := $(shell node -p "require('./package.json').description")
PROJECT_URL := $(shell node -p "require('./package.json').repository.url")
```

Is this the only way? Maybe there is a way to create kind of a list.

Comment: How long does a `node` invocation take? Is it worth the micro-optimization? As-is, it looks pretty readable--a property that I would not sacrifice for an obfuscated optimized `make` hackery.

Comment: @Jens Indeed, it doesn't affect performance at all, maybe let it as-is.

Comment: If a single `node` invocation could print all four items, you'd have the problem of separating them. Since `make` by nature uses space-separated lists, I'd expect the "description" member to be problematic since the description likely contains spaces. You'd have to create output with a special delimiter (comma? Semicolon?), with all the escaping problems that entails.

Comment: As long as the json file is local, follow Jens' advice

Comment: @Jens and Alex, thank you guys. I guess this is the best (only) way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

At the end, I came up with this:

```
define GetFromPkg
$(shell node -p "require('./package.json').$(1)")
endef

PROJECT      := $(call GetFromPkg,name)
LAST_VERSION := $(call GetFromPkg,version)
DESCRIPTION  := $(call GetFromPkg,description)
PROJECT_URL  := $(call GetFromPkg,repository.url)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that _make_ does not strip spaces from parameters in a `$(call ...)`. You get away with it here because `node -p "require('./package.json'). name"` is still valid. (`$(call GetFromPkg,name)` is probably more in the _make_ idiom IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tweaked version of the accepted answer.

It enables to easily get nested values by invoking `GetValueFromJson` with an argument like `data.profile.name`.

```sh
define GetValueFromJson
$(shell node -p '\
    const getVal = (key = "", obj = {}) => {
          const currKey = key.split(".")[0];
          const val = obj[currKey];
          if(typeof val !== "object") return val;
          const nextKey = key.split(".").slice(1).join(".");
          return getVal(nextKey, val);
    }; \
    getVal(`$(1)`.replace(" ", ""), require("./package.json")); \
')
endef

PORT := $(call GetValueFromJson, config.port)

# make run
run:
    PORT=${PORT} node server.js
```